# How to create instance specific methods for each instance of a class?

Tags: c++, class, methods

I'm making a card game in C++ and I've made a a Button Class with an onClick() method. Every card is going to be a button, but I wan't each card to do something different when clicked. Is there a way to do this by somehow overriding the onClick() function for every instance, instead of creating 50 different class methods or 50 different classes?

I've tried creating a function for each different instance and passing it as a field in the class. Then, the onClick() function acts as a wrapper for each instance and calls the function passed as an argument in the Button constructor, but I'm trying to avoid adding a function argument in the Button constructor.

Comment: What's the difference between cards' `onClick()` functions?

Comment: It really depends, you could depending on the situation, create a bunch of components and have each card hold a collection of relevant components. But that may be overkill, I reckon the simplest thing to do may be your suggestion of passing a function to your button's constructor. But that's only really if each function is unique enough, it's hard to give a definite answer without more context. Also, what's the reasoning behind "but I'm trying to avoid adding a function argument in the Button constructor."?

Comment: Could this be an example for the XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? I would expect the method do something different but very similar for each card type. Wouldn't a card type field and distinction depending on the card type be an appropriate solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible solutions. One that popped up in my min is that you could have an array of 50 function pointers (or rather `std::function` objects) that each point to a function to handle the specific "card". Or just have a single such `std::function` object that you initialize to the correct function in the constructor initializer list (for example).

And if there's very little differing between the functions, perhaps it would be wiser to collect it into a single function anyway, and have e.g. a `switch` statement to do the little specific pieces that differs?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is commonly known as *higher-order programming* and [function-objects](/questions/tagged/function-objects)

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you may want to use eg. `std::function`([std-function](/questions/tagged/std-function))  and store that on the card class - *like you say*. But since you don't want to pass it in the constructor (*why ?*) you could make the member optional eg. `std::optional<std::function<void()> >`

Comment: I get the feeling that the op knows about passing functions around, given their second paragraph.

Comment: In fact the question literally says they don't want to do this